# Printing an index number of dictionary entry, PLUS it's key, plus it's value

Tags: python, python-3.x, finance

## Suppose we have the following dataframe

```
import yfinance as yf 
import numpy as np
import numpy_financial as npf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from os import system
import sys, time
import pandas as pd
import requests


import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

url_link = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/analysis?p=TSLA'
r = requests.get(url_link,headers ={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'})

data = pd.read_html(r.text)
data = data[0]
data = data[data['Earnings Estimate'] == 'Avg. Estimate']

data.plot(kind='bar')

data = yf.Ticker("TSLA")
```

### The following operations are easy

```
for key, value in data.info.items():
    print(f"{key} : {value}")
    print("")
```

This prints out each of dictionary entries line by line, with a space in between.

```
keys_list = list(data.info.keys())
values_list = list(data.info.values())
```

These operations separate the keys and values of the dictionary into their own distinct lists.  This makes it possible to do one of the following two operations...

```
for key in data.info.keys():
    print(str(keys_list.index(key)) + ". " + str( key ))  

for value in data.info.values():
    print(str(values_list.index(value)) + ". " + str( value ))
```

either of these are fine, and what they do is print out an index number, plus the sring value of the item in the list.

### But what I would like to is print out an index number, then the key, and then the value,

so that the output format looks something like

```
1. key: value
2. key: value
3: key: value
```

I've tried creating a variable to represent an integer alongside the key/values in a for loop, but  I get the following error message

```
valueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

So really I'm not sure what else I should try to wrangle the output to the desired format.

Comment: Please add the code that's getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `items()` to get the keys and values together. Use `enumerate()` to return an index along with the values form an iterator.

```
for i, (key, value) in enumerate(data.info.items(), 1):
    print(f"{i}. {key}: {value}")
```

Notice that you have to group `key` and `value` in a tuple, because that's what `items()` returns for each element.

Comment: Problem Solved!  Thank you!!!